# Can't generate a table from a .csv file

Tags: pgfplotstable

I am trying to generate table from .csv file.
Firstly, I create an excel spreadsheet that looks like this:

[image]

Then I export it as a .csv file, that looks like this:

[image]

Then I use the following code to generate the table:

```
\usepackage{booktabs} % for \toprule, \midrule, \bottomrule.
\usepackage{siunitx} % for formatting units and values.
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} % for generating tables form .csv files.

\sisetup{ % setting up the siunitx package
    round-mode=places, % round numbers
    round-precision=2  % up to the second digit
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h!]
        \begin{center}
        \caption{Auto-generated table from .csv file.}
        \label{tab:students}
        \pgfplotstabletypeset[
             multicolumn names, % allows to have multicolumn names
             col sep=comma,     % the separator in our .csv file
             display columns/0/.style={
                 column name=$Students$,  % name of 1st column
                 column type={S},string type},
             display columns/1/.style={
                 column name=$Heights [cm]$, % name of 2nd column
                 column type={S},string type},
             display columns/2/.style={
               column name=$Weights [kg]$, % name of 3rd column
               column type={S},string type},
             every head row/.style={
               before row={\toprule},
               after row={\si{Name} & \si{cm} & \si{kg}\\ 
              \midrule}
             },
             every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
            ]{HeightsAndWeights.csv}
        \end{center}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

The result I get looks like this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?
What should I correct, add or remove?

Comment: Can we please also see the contents of the csv, not a picture.

Comment: Yes, just a second

Comment: Well from your image at the end it is pretty clear what the problem is, it is not really a normal CSV file, it is separated by **semi-colon** not **comma**, this is sadly pretty normal with Excel, so you should presumably just change `col sep`

Comment: You want to use `,` as a separator, but the file uses `;`

Comment: And by the way: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example using a *true* csv file and some modifications

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for \toprule, \midrule, \bottomrule.
\usepackage{siunitx} % for formatting units and values.
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} % for generating tables form .csv files.

\sisetup{ % setting up the siunitx package
    round-mode=places, % round numbers
    round-precision=2  % up to the second digit
}

\begin{filecontents*}{file.csv}
Peter, 150, 45
Jason, 134, 39
Stefan, 139, 41
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h!]
        \begin{center}
        \caption{Auto-generated table from .csv file.}
        \label{tab:students}
        \pgfplotstabletypeset[
             multicolumn names, % allows to have multicolumn names
             col sep=comma,     % the separator in our .csv file
             display columns/0/.style={column name=Students, column type={c},string type},
             display columns/1/.style={column name=Heights, column type={S},string type},
             display columns/2/.style={column name=Weights,column type={S},string type},
             every head row/.style={before row={\toprule},after row={Name & {\si{\centi\meter}} & {\si{\kilo\gram}}\\\midrule}},
             every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
            ]{file.csv}
        \end{center}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]